# Could Andrei Volkov stop complaining about me?

Tags: discussion

I have no idea what is bugging them, I've said nothing offensive and they keep complaining I'm a "lost cause".

It's not like they're my teacher, or even that we practice with the same tradition etc..

I've enjoyed lots of their answers, but I find this behaviour unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I will stop if that's what you want.

At first I wanted to simply ignore your questions/answers - but then I thought that perhaps I should apply some compassion and try to engage, however hopeless you appear - but now I see that you interpret my helpful hand as offence. It's okay I guess, not everyone can be helped.

Comment: i'm not offended, i just find it helpful. it's fine

Answer (score 1):

I think it was "lost *case*" (like a koan), not "cause", for what that's worth.

On both occasions (this was the second I've seen recently) that was in reply to comment of yours, where you criticised an answer or a comment -- recently,

> - this is not very informative without references etc., it just reads like just so stories
> - Like I said, lost case. I will leave this answer for the sake of other people then.

I didn't read Andrei's reply as "started complaining about you" -- I read it as a decision not to address your criticism by posting an addition or correction. And maybe that's right since this site is meant to be for answerable questions, not for discussions (nor arguments).

Incidentally Andrei posted [this meta-answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/117/254) a while ago -- about references etc.

And there were some references in a previous answer [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/12735/254).

I think it takes a bit of effort to ask a good question, effort to write an answer, and effort to ask a good follow-up question in a comment.

You might read [this Help topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) especially **When should I comment?** and **When *shouldn't* I comment?**

If I do "request clarification from the author" then I think I tend to phrase my comment as a specific question, with a question mark -- not a comment like, "this answer wasn't very informative."

Comment: it's not an isolated case, he's encouraging people to be hostile to me

Comment: As I wrote: I see "lost" in a comment, on two occasions, they were both in a similar situation. If someone is hostile to you, you can "flag" that for a moderator's attention. Still I (personally) recommend that you (that everyone, in fact) be careful when you comment on what other people's posts (including Andrei's): perhaps go out of your way to be polite ... and/or avoid commenting.

Comment: i am being polite, but if someone makes an unclear or unreferenced reply to my question -- ESPECIALLY if they seem to be correcting something i said -- i think i should downvote and leave a comment why

Comment: and i'm not going to "report" every comment by someone that took offense to that and wants to reinforce their sense of superiority

Comment: @sorta_buddhist When my brother and I used to complain to my mum about each other, she'd tell us that we *both* had to "stop it". And that's what I'm telling you -- i.e. that you have to stop it. `and i'm not going to "report" every comment` You can but you don't have to. I generally read every comment whether it's flagged or not. But it's better to delete any hostile comments, a) to stop arguments and b) to make the site more pleasant for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that people use the site to show off their esoteric awareness of reality, so that when you point out their answer is unclear or poorly referenced, they think you're insulting their attainments or wisdom.